# Avoiding Repition in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to this site/coding and I had a question regarding CSS.  I apologize if this question appears elsewhere.

Let's say you have created a div (call it div1) and you have styled it with CSS.  If you want to duplicate this div 10 times, but make very minor changes to each one, can you keep the div as a .class and if so, how do I go about making the minor changes to each div?

Comment: Add a class to each duplicated div and style those classes,

Comment: id can be used once, yes class is the way, for the rest you have nth-child selector, or the possibility to select element from their parents via tag names, classnames or id. often id or class within child can be avoided. id are useful for javascript and anchors for instance. else other attributes can be used as selectors. You have many option to style precisely a child somewhere in the dom  even if it has no id nor class set

Comment: you should really give a sample of your html structure to avoid being downvoted and in order to get efficient answers ...

Comment: There is really no need for him to give a code sample. His question is pretty clear.

Comment: @Gendarme not to me  as I commented. if strutcture is using html5 tags such as header, aside , article, section , and so on , or a repeated block, id and class don't even need to be used for styling, a complexe structure can provide many (complexe) precise selector going down the almost anywhere you wish ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can give them a class name and style every element of that class the same way. For the minor changes you can use the `id` attribute (or even inline-CSS).

For example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "box" id = "first">
  ...
</div>
<div class = "box" id = "second">
  ...
</div>
<div class = "box" id = "third">
  ...
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    background-color: red;
    color: blue;
}

#first {
    color: yellow;
}

#second {
    color: green;
}

#third {
    color: white;
}
```

However, keep in mind that it is better to use tags that describe your layout instead of calling everything `<div>` and giving them classes (i.e `<section>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>`, `<main>`, `<nav>`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's assume you have a div with a class of `default`

```
<div class="default">Default Div</div>
```

Now you can style it with css as follows:

```
.default {
     font:16px;
     padding:5px;
}
```

Now suppose you have a new div with similar styles to default div but you want more padding or want to change text color red. Then you can add a class named `red` or `extra-padding` to your new div. This way you can then create another style rule in your css below the `.default` class styles. The important thing is that the default class will also be applied to those new divs in addition to the new classes that you define. For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="default red">Default style plus green styles</div>
<div class="default extra-padding">Default style plus green styles</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red {
   color:red;
}

.extra-padding {
   padding:10px;
}
```

Note that in `.red` class only additional styles or required modifications would be defined since remaining styles are defined in the `.default` class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably just to add two classes to each div: one that all divs share, then one class that is unique to each div and holds the differing styling info. See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZJVjo

```
<div class="common format-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div class="common format-2">
  <p>Ea animi error distinctio enim.</p>
</div>
<div class="common format-3">
  <p>Laborum aut, dicta sit quasi.</p>
</div>
<div class="common format-4">
  <p>Est laborum magnam nemo, cupiditate.</p>
</div>
<div class="common format-5">
  <p>Dolorum, eveniet reiciendis quidem iure!</p>
</div>

.common {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.format-1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.format-2 {
  color: blue;
}

.format-3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.format-4 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.format-5 {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

You could put all of the common styling on `<div>` but using classes for both the common and unique styling will make things easier as your code gets bigger.

Comment: unique-x  would be an id that it would be the same :)

Comment: That's assuming you had no need to reuse the styling for unique-x @GCyrillus

Comment: A fair assumption, however I know I've seen some terribly named classes before. Always best not to assume ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this one of two ways.

1. Give each div an ID and use css to target each ID for its minor changes
   ex.

```css
.class{
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  }

#id1{
  background: rgb(125,0,125);
  }
#id2{
  background: rgb(255,0,0);
  }
#id3{
  background: rgb(0,255,0);
  }
#id4{
  background: rgb(0,0,255);
  }
#id5{
  background: rgb(255,255,0);
  }
#id6{
  background: rgb(0,255,255);
  }
#id7{
  background: rgb(255,0,255);
  }
#id8{
  background: rgb(255,255,125);
  }
#id9{
  background: rgb(255,125,0);
  }
#id10{
  background: rgb(125,0,255);
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="id1" class="class">This is div1</div> 
  <div id="id2" class="class">This is div2</div> 
  <div id="id3" class="class">This is div3</div> 
  <div id="id4" class="class">This is div4</div> 
  <div id="id5" class="class">This is div5</div> 
  <div id="id6" class="class">This is div6</div> 
  <div id="id7" class="class">This is div7</div> 
  <div id="id8" class="class">This is div8</div> 
  <div id="id9" class="class">This is div9</div> 
  <div id="id10" class="class">This is div10</div>  
</body>
```

2. If styling may be reused for other elements as well, you can add multiple classes to the elements.
   ex.

```css
.class{
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  }

.c1{
  background: rgb(125,0,125);
  }
.c2{
  background: rgb(255,0,0);
  }
.c3{
  background: rgb(0,255,0);
  }
.c4{
  background: rgb(0,0,255);
  }
.c5{
  background: rgb(255,255,0);
  }
.c6{
  background: rgb(0,255,255);
  }
.c7{
  background: rgb(255,0,255);
  }
.c8{
  background: rgb(255,255,125);
  }
.c9{
  background: rgb(255,125,0);
  }
.c10{
  background: rgb(125,0,255);
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="class c1">This is div1</div> 
  <div class="class c2">This is div2</div> 
  <div class="class c3">This is div3</div> 
  <div class="class c4">This is div4</div> 
  <div class="class c5">This is div5</div> 
  <div class="class c6">This is div6</div> 
  <div class="class c7">This is div7</div> 
  <div class="class c8">This is div8</div> 
  <div class="class c9">This is div9</div> 
  <div class="class c10">This is div10</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Wow. You did not really have to create 10 different `<div>` elements. It makes your post unnecessarily effortful to read. **Edit:** Nvm. I didn't notice OP asked for 10 different `<div>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid repetition and want to come up with cleaner css code, I recommend using SASS.

For example, it provides a feature called "extend", which allows for constructs like this.

```
.myClass
  padding: 10px
  margin: 15px
  background: black
  font-size: 2rem
  ...


.myClassAbitDifferent
  @extend myClass
  background: white
```

But before you dive deep into SASS I would suggest to master the basic concepts of CSS. Here's a good tutorial about it!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7ONvIgOWdM&list=PLqGj3iMvMa4IOmy04kDxh_hqODMqoeeCy

Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create one #id for each div with different specification or if they have repeatable code append new classes.

Example:

```
<div id="myA" class="box"></div>
<div id="myB" class="box"></div>
<div id="myC" class="box"></div>
```

Where a is background-color equal to blue, b equal to red, etc.
Or

```
<div class="box red"></div>
<div class="box blue"></div>
<div class="box green"></div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8bbx0o1/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Please supply a code sample. It makes it easier. What I think you want is [nth-child()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) or [nth-of-type()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp). You can also give them different class names but all the same id.

```
<div id="same" class="different">
</div>
<div id="same" class="moreDifferent">
</div>
```

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbhdgkjf/)

Comment: IDs should *always* be **unique**. If you write this the other way around, unique IDs and common classes, then it would be fine.

Comment: You probably mean *different IDs but with the same class name*. IDs cannot be shared between two elements. They are unique.

Comment: you did it the other way round than supposed to be done ;)